# R studio: How to calculate the standard error/deviation in a t test for the two groups?

Tags: standard-deviation, t-test

I just started using r studio and I want to calculate an independent two sample t test. In order to report the results I should report the mean and standard deviation of each group. The output only gives me the means of each group. How can I calculate the SD?

This is the command I used for the t test:

t.test(deontological_inclination ~ condition, data = data_complete)